# How do I list the array number which has the highest value?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

In a current assignment I am trying to print out the array which has the highest value along with the array number itself. However with the code I have it is printing the array number as the same as the the array value. With the input values of 4, 9, 3, 7, and 6 the output should be Day #2 with 9 hours worked, but it outputs Day #9 with 9 hours worked. Any help appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter hours worked on day #1: ");
        int Day1hours = userinput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter hours worked on day #2: ");
        int Day2hours = userinput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter hours worked on day #3: ");
        int Day3hours = userinput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter hours worked on day #4: ");
        int Day4hours = userinput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter hours worked on day #5: ");
        int Day5hours = userinput.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> day = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        day.add(Day1hours);
        day.add(Day2hours);
        day.add(Day3hours);
        day.add(Day4hours);
        day.add(Day5hours);
        double avg;
        int sum = 0;
        int mosthours = Collections.max(day);

        System.out.println("The most hours worked was on: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < day.size(); i++) {
            int daywithmosthours = day.get(i);
            if (day.get(i) == mosthours) {
                System.out.println("Day #" + daywithmosthours + " when you worked " + mosthours + " Hours.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `day.get(i)` gives the value at `i`; the values you have stored in `day` are the hours worked each day, so that value is a number of hours.

Comment: As a side note, any time you're repeating the same thing more than twice, there's probably a better way to be doing it. In this case, you could be using a loop to get input, rather than repeating the `Prints` and `nextInt()` calls hard-coded five times over.

Comment: And the five different `DayNhours` variables are not needed, even without a loop.  `day.add(userinput.nextInt())` works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for-loop. Change it into

```
for (int i = 0; i < day.size(); i++) {
    int daywithmosthours = i;
    if (day.get(i) == mosthours) {
        System.out.println("Day #" + daywithmosthours + " when you worked " + mosthours + " Hours.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer

```
int daywithmosthours = day.get(i);
```

should be

```
int daywithmosthours = i;
```

This will get you the **day index rather than the value at the index. How ever index start with 0 and it will be one less than the expected value**. You should add +1 to fix this.
For a beginners standpoint this program will work , but this can be improved further as mentioned in the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your use of `Collections.max(day)` is cheating.

Here's probably how most people would solve this assignment:

```
  public static void main( String [] args) {   
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> day = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      System.out.print("Enter hours worked on day #" + i + ": ");
      day.add(userinput.nextInt());  
    }

    int index = 0;
    int max = day.get(index);
    for (int i=1; i<day.size(); i++) {
      int cur = day.get(i);
      if (cur > max) {
        max = cur;
        index = i;
      }
    }
    
    System.out.println("The most hours worked was on: ");
    System.out.println("\tDay #" + (index+1) + " when you worked " + max + " Hours.");
  }
```